# Java, need to validate null on binary search

Tags: java

I need to validate the null value of the array when I'm using the binary search.

I have this code:

```
public String search(int search) {

    int first = 0;
    int last = vector.length - 1;
    int center;
    while (first <= last) {
        center = (first + last) / 2;

        if (search == vector[center].getValue() {
            return "Found: " + vector[center].getIdentificationValue() + "\n";
        } else if (search < vector[center].getValue) {
            first = center - 1;
        } else {
            last = center + 1;
        }
    }
    return "Not Found";
}
```

The validation I have to do is:

- I have the vector `[1,2,3,4,null,null,null]`, and
- I do the search of 4, when the binary search reach the `null` start again with the value in the pos [0].

Comment: it would help if you could tell us what `vector` is.

Comment: the vector is [1,2,3,4,null,null,null]

Comment: is just a vector for test

Comment: Your stated validation is incomprehensible. It seems to just loop forever as you describe it. Try and explain it again in a way that is understandable to people who don't know whatever it is you think you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The array should not contain `null` at all. From your example, it seems as if the `null`s only occurred at the end of the array. If you know how many array elements are "good", just do the binary search in the range `(0, firstNullIndex)`.